# VBA - run time error 1004 Rows of Object Global Failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime, rows

Have this code written in word VBA to get data from excel and when I run the below code, it works perfectly but sometimes get runtime error 1004 "Method 'Rows' of object Global failed" for "lrow" line. Cant figure how to overcome this error?

```
Sub copyPW()
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim PW As Excel.Workbook
Dim Dlog As FileDialog
objExcel.Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveDocument.Select
Selection.TypeBackspace
Set Dlog = Application.FileDialog( _
FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogOpen)
With Dlog
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "Title"
    If .Show = True Then
    Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
Set PW = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path)

' the next line
lrow = PW.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

For R = 16 To lrow
If PW.Sheets(1).Cells(R, 4) = "O" Then
Selection.TypeText PW.Sheets(1).Cells(R, 6)
Selection.TypeParagraph
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to show how the global lrow is defined

Comment: You need to qualify the `Rows` call with a worksheet too: `PW.Sheets(1).Cells(PW.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row`